# Opta Planner like as configuration

Tags: configuration, optaplanner

I want to use the Opta Planner configuration with as configuration, by example:

If you have a list of element, like to selection a type of car (In this case the inputs (variables) are brand, tire, motor, color).
We'd have(domains) for

brand: A,B,C,D,E; tire: G,H,I,J,K; motor: M,N,O,P,Q; Color: R,S,T,U,V.

To select a Color R, my domain will restricted by the constraint, and then we'll have:

brand: A,B,C; tire: G,H,I; motor: M,P,Q; Color: R

and, select tire G, and then solution is: brand: B; tire: G; motor: M; Color: R

In this example, I don't want a specific solution for first moment, but I want to propagate in accurs with my requeriments until to the solution. Is it possible with OptaPlanner? and where can I find more about propagate in OptaPlanner?

I try to open example

Comment: You might be better off with a decision table than a constraint solver for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to restrict the domain of other variables based on the current value of another variable. This is not possible, as that would only try to make the planning entity solve the planning problem itself and interfere with the optimization algorithms.

Something that closely related is "ValueRangeProvider on the Planning Entity" (https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/planner-configuration/planner-configuration.html#valueRangeProviderOnPlanningEntity), where the domain depends on problem facts (which cannot change during solving).

If you want full control on how the domain changes, consider a custom move selector (https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/move-and-neighborhood-selection/move-and-neighborhood-selection.html#customMoves) or a custom solver phase (https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/optimization-algorithms/optimization-algorithms.html#customSolverPhase).